# Очень долго выключается ноутбук, Ubuntu

Tags: linux, lubuntu

Установил Lubuntu 16.04. Все работает нормально, но в последнее время ноутбук не выключается.

Для выключение ноутбука, мне приходится зажимать кнопку выключения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение.

Мой ноутбук:

[image: Aspire ES 15]
Aspire ES 15 ( https://market.yandex.by/product/1715643215/spec?hid=91013&track=tabs )

При выключении:

[image: poweroff]

Comment: что происходит для каждой из команд: `systemctl poweroff`, `systemctl poweroff -f`, `systemctl poweroff -ff`, `sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff`

Comment: Завтра на работе попробую. А если одна из комманд адекватно выключит комп?

Comment: Это сузит возможный список причин, по которым сейчас не выключается (разные могут быть причины).

Comment: Вы не написали ни версии ядра, ни название и модель ноутбука, изболеет того не приложили ссылку на вывод команд *lsmod*, *dmesg*, *lspci -n*. Что вы хотите получить в ответе -- гадание на кофейной гуще?

Comment: 0andriy, исправился.

Comment: jfs, systemctl poweroff - тоже самое; systemctl poweroff -f только последняя строчка - [ 490.070934] reboot: Power down

Comment: при systemctl poweroff -ff в терминале в ответ написало Powering off и потом все зависло. Думаю надо зажимать кнопочку на 5 сек.

Comment: sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff выдало черный экран с кучей строк, как на скриншоте. И в конце последняя строка [ 163.724902] reboot: Power down

Comment: 0andriy, как мне дать ссылку на вывод команд, ели каждая с них выводит по 3 метра строк.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра, используйте сторонние сервисы типа pastebin, а сюда кидайте линки. И пишите @ перед никами, случайно увидел обновление здесь.

Comment: `pci=nocrs` если добавить в командную строку ядра при загрузке помогает?

Answer (score -1):

"reboot: Power down" У меня тоже недавно начал писать эту надпись, она не мешает выключению. Ось Archlinux.

При выключении systemd ожидает некоторое время, пока каждая служба завершит свою работу самостоятельно, и только потом пытается принудительно завершить (kill) ее.
Systemd это такой грузила, самая первая программа которую запустило ядро. Она загружает всевозможные модули (дровишки) и др.

**1.** Debug, определяем службу которая мешает быстрому выключению компьютера.
Многие предлагают врубить systemd debug, хорошо.

Нам нужно приписать debug аргументы к ядру, то, что я делаю, сработает только с grub загрузчиком, grub поставляется по умолчанию в той же Ubuntu.

Правим аргументы ядра. Откройте терминал. Вводим `sudo -s` и приступаем.

```
nano /etc/default/grub  #откроем в консольном редакторе нужный нам файл
```

Прочитать как пользоваться `nano`: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/nano

Приводим строку `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="+что-то написано+"` к такому виду:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="+что-то написано+ systemd.log_level=debug systemd.log_target=kmsg log_buf_len=1M printk.devkmsg=on enforcing=0 "
```

Закрываем с сохранением.

Дальше требуется обновить конфиги `grub`:

Пишем `update-grub` или `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
На всякий пожарный `mkdir -p /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/`.

Теперь приступим к скрипту, который будет исполнятся при выключении:
`nano /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/debug.sh`

Пишем в него это:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -o remount,rw /
dmesg > /shutdown-log.txt
mount -o remount,ro /
```

На всякий, сделаем исполняемым: `chmod a+x /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/debug.sh`

Перезагружайтесь два раза! При выключении systemd запишет подробный лог в файл `/shutdown-log.txt` о том, что нам мешает выключаться! Искать нам нужно так называемые таймауты или то, что связано с systemd.

**2.** После определения проблемы, отключить ее или найти способ ее усмирить.

Если это обьекты systemd, то

```
systemctl disable +служба+
```

или

```
systemctl mask +служба+
```

**3.** Возможно уменьшить интервал ожидания убийства обьектов systemd при выключении.

Терминал. **sudo -s** и это.

```
nano /etc/systemd/user.conf
```

Находим такие строчки

```
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
```

Приводим к `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=8s` *(убрали #, изменили секунды)*

Если не ошибся с этим пунктом. Этот пункт конечно не правильный, но подойдет.

```
#Ulin
```

Comment: `/shutdown-log.txt` не создаётся на моей машине с Ubuntu 16.04. Эти шаги предлагаются на странице [Diagnosing Shutdown Problems](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#index2h1).

Comment: Пришлите  cat /proc/cmdline

Comment: +Пришлите ls -sl /usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/debug.sh

Comment: 1- cmdline соответствует GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT из ответа 2- `debug.sh` совпадал с тем что указано в моей ссылке (и что у вас в ответе приведено). Опять таки copy-paste.

Comment: во-первых, файл /etc/default/grub у меня вообще пустой. Во-вторых, соответственно, файл /shutdown-log.txt не создался.

Comment: "во-первых, файл /etc/default/grub у меня вообще пустой" Он не может быть пуст.  Вы видемо его извели.  http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/grub